# Prometheus/Micrometer: how to count discrete values instead integral

Tags: java, prometheus, micrometer

I'm trying to use Java-library  "io.micrometer.core.instrument" for counting some values in different intervals of time.

So with Counter my code looks like this:

```
private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;
private Counter attemptsCount;

@PostConstruct
private void initCounter() {
    attemptsCount = Counter.builder("ATTEMPTS_COUNT")
            .tag("type", "word")
            .description("Attempts number count")
            .register(meterRegistry);
}

public void incrementAttemptsCount(final int sendAttemptsCount) {   
    attemptsCount.increment(sendAttemptsCount);
    attemptsCount.count();       
}
```

In test-case client code 3 times pass to incrementAttemptsCount-method  following values: 3, 3, 3.

Initially I expected, my micrometer-code generate 3 values of metric: 3, 3, 3  and pass it to Prometheus. And, using Graphana-tools, I will see histogram, which reflects discrete values. Something like this:

[image: histogram1]

But instead of this I see:

[image]

So it integrates values (3+3+3) and output 9.

How to provide output of discrete values of metric (3, 3, 3)? What instrument should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts), [Counters](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_counters) are summing values (I'm not sure what do you mean by integral). When you are *counting* something, you are keeping the sum in mind. Although when a counter is exported, it's not the sum that is interesting but the rate of that sum (first derivative by time), you can read about this in the docs under [Rate aggregation](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#rate-aggregation).

Based on my understanding what you need is a [Gauge](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_gauges); Gauges are used for getting the current value.